# Precision problem when dividing Double values in Haskell

Tags: haskell, precision, division

I am trying to divide a double precision floating point number (`Double`) by `2.0` one hundred times successively in Haskell.

When I get the value `5960464477539.06250`, dividing this value by `2.00000` results in `2.9802322387695313e12` (or `2980232238769.53130`). Mathematically, the correct result would be `2980232238769.53125`, but there is some loss of precision here.

```
import Text.Printf (printf)
import System.Exit (exitSuccess)

main = do
   n <- readLn :: IO Double
   reading n 0

reading n c = do
   if c == 100
      then exitSuccess
      else printf "%.5f\n" n
   reading (n/2.0) (c+1)
```

Dividing the values directly in `ghci`:

```
Prelude> 5960464477539.06250/2
2.9802322387695313e12
```

I already read about `Data.Scientific`, but I don't have access to this module. Without it, is there any way to improve accuracy in this case?

Comment: Actually, dividing by 2 is always exact (at least until you saturate the negative exponent). The *starting* value already lost precision, you just can't see that fact from the way it's printed.

Comment: @DanielWagner I suspected this, as one of my unsuccessful strategies was trying to separate the integer and decimal parts, which already resulted in different values. Any idea how I can solve this problem?

Comment: First: are you *sure* it's a problem? It would be pretty unusual for that level of precision to matter. However, if you absolutely must have that level of precision, you can use one of `CReal` (exact, slow, library supports printing in the format you describe), `Rational` (exact, intermediate speed, library code has specialized printing format), or `Fixed` (inexact, fast, library supports printing in your format).

Comment: @DanielWagner Absolutely. Thank you for showing me a way.

Comment: In the process of writing up an answer I discovered that my first comment is wrong. Actually, the correct explanation is that dividing by 2 results in the exact mathematically correct result, even in your example code; it's just that `Double`s are not printed as their exact decimal representation, but as the shortest decimal representation that uniquely identifies a `Double` value, and the closest `Double` to `2.9802322387695313e12` is `2.98023223876953125e12`.

Comment: Frankly, if you depended on a destinction between `2980232238769.53130` and `2980232238769.53125` it means you were either doing cutting-edge metrology research, or thinking fundamentally wrong about what floating-point numbers (or indeed _real numbers_) are supposed to be and do.

Comment: ...And I rather doubt that switching to a type like `Pico` is a sensible thing to do either. Instead, you should just not do things with these numbers that depend on this kind of equality.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, your number has been computed with full precision; it's just that when printing `Double`s, the standard thing to do is to only print as many digits as needed to uniquely identify a `Double`, and in this case that's fewer than all of them after dividing by 2. You can write your own routine for turning a `Double` into an exact decimal representation with all digits if you like; you use the usual division+modular reduction trick that's used for showing digits of a normal integer, but with a bit of extra logic for inserting a decimal point when the ratio drops below 1.

But... I've always meant to put together a routine for turning an arbitrary-precision `Rational` into a sequence of digits in an arbitrary base + information on where the sequence loops, so I took this as an excuse to finally do it. This can also be used to double-check the fact I stated above about full precision being available in your starting code. Here's the data type we'll produce as our end result:

```
import Data.Ratio
import Data.Map (Map)
import qualified Data.Map as M

data Sign = Pos | Neg deriving (Bounded, Enum, Eq, Ord, Read, Show)

data Digits = Digits
    { intro :: [Integer]
    , loop :: [Integer]
    , power :: Int
    , sign :: Sign
    , base :: Integer
    } deriving (Eq, Ord, Read, Show)
```

The intention is that `d` represents the sequence of digits `intro d ++ cycle (loop d)` (plus some handy auxiliary information). Here's how you can compute it:

```
normalizeMagnitude :: Integer -> Rational -> (Rational, Int)
normalizeMagnitude base_ = go where
    base = fromInteger base_
    go x
        | x >= base = succ <$> go (x/base)
        | x < 1 = pred <$> go (x*base)
        | otherwise = (x, 0)

buildLoop :: Integer -> Rational -> (Map Rational (Integer, Rational), Rational)
buildLoop base = go M.empty where
    go seen x = if x `M.member` seen then (seen, x) else go (M.insert x (d, x') seen) x' where
        (d, m) = numerator x `divMod` denominator x
        x' = (m * base) % denominator x

reifyUntil :: Ord a => Map a (b, a) -> a -> a -> [b]
reifyUntil m a0 = go where
    go a = if a0 == a then [] else case M.lookup a m of
        Nothing -> error "never reached sentinel"
        Just (b, a') -> b : go a'

reifyLoop :: Ord a => Map a (b, a) -> a -> [b]
reifyLoop m a0 = case M.lookup a0 m of
    Nothing -> error "not actually a loop"
    Just (b, a) -> b : reifyUntil m a0 a

digits :: Integer -> Rational -> Digits
digits b x = Digits
    { intro = reifyUntil digitMap loopSentinel xNorm
    , loop = reifyLoop digitMap loopSentinel
    , power = p
    , sign = s
    , base = b
    } where
    (xPos, s) = if x < 0 then (-x, Neg) else (x, Pos)
    (xNorm, p) = normalizeMagnitude b xPos
    (digitMap, loopSentinel) = buildLoop b xNorm
```

There are various ways you might want to pretty-print this into a `String`. Here's one:

```
pp :: (Integer -> ShowS) -> Digits -> ShowS
pp showDigit d = foldr (.) id $ tail [undefined
    , case sign d of
        Pos -> id
        Neg -> ('-':)
    , showDigit x
    , case (xs, xs') of
        ([], [0]) -> id
        _ -> ('.':) . showDigits xs
    , case xs' of
        [0] -> id
        _ -> ('(':) . showDigits xs' . ("...)"++)
    , case (power d, base d) of
        (0, _) -> id
        (_, 10) -> ('e':)
        _ -> ('*':) . shows (base d) . ('^':)
    , case power d of
        0 -> id
        _ -> shows (power d)
    ]
    where
    showDigits = foldr (\digit f -> showDigit digit . f) id
    (x:xs, xs') = case intro d of
        [] -> case loop d of
            [] -> error "invalid digits"
            x:xs -> ([x], xs ++ [x])
        _ -> (intro d, loop d)
```

We can try it out in ghci:

```
> pp shows (digits 10 5960464477539.0625) ""
"5.9604644775390625e12"
> pp shows (digits 10 (5960464477539.0625/2)) ""
"2.98023223876953125e12"
```

Full precision is retained. We can also now verify the first paragraph of the answer by doing all the calculations in `Double` and then converting to `Rational` just before printing:

```
> pp shows (digits 10 (toRational (5960464477539.0625 :: Double))) ""
"5.9604644775390625e12"
> pp shows (digits 10 (toRational (5960464477539.0625/2 :: Double))) ""
"2.98023223876953125e12"
```

Full precision is retained even for the `Double`-based calculation.

Comment: I would certainly gain a few more gray hairs until I get this solution. I will test it this way too. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved my problem with the accuracy I wanted (thanks to Daniel Wagner).

I used the `Pico` type (`Fixed E12`), resolution of 10^-12 = .000000000001, from `Data.Fixed` module. Although it is inaccurate, it is reasonable for the accuracy I needed and easy to format. Here is a working draft:

```
import Data.Fixed

main :: IO ()
main = do
   n <- readLn :: IO Pico
   reading n 0

roundNew :: Pico -> Integer -> Pico
roundNew n precision = fromIntegral (round (n * 10^precision)) / 10^precision

reading n index = do
   if c == 100
      then return ()
      else do
         putStrLn (show (roundNew n 5))
         reading (n/2.0) (c+1)
```